# Error installing Ruby on Mac for Github Pages

Tags: ruby, macos, github-pages

I am a moderately experienced programmer but am new to Ruby, and I'm having a hard time installing it so I can get Github Pages set up. I'm running a 2015 MacBook Pro on 12.7 macOS Monterey, with an Intel Core i7 processor.

I have tried both
`ruby-install 3.1.3` and  `ruby-install 3.1.3 -- --enable-shared`, as well as `rbenv install 3.1.3` but received the following error for all three:

```
linking miniruby
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_coroutine_transfer", referenced from:
      _fiber_setcontext in cont.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [miniruby] Error 1
!!! Compiling ruby 3.1.3 failed!
```

`brew config` returns:

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 4.1.16
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: c0c8a4dd4dd19ec16deb429abd50cdf82ea33b27
Last commit: 5 days ago
Core tap JSON: 20 Oct 00:15 UTC
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: []
HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 8
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.10 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby
CPU: octa-core 64-bit haswell
Clang: 14.0.0 build 1400
Git: 2.14.1 => /usr/local/bin/git
Curl: 8.1.2 => /usr/bin/curl
macOS: 12.7-x86_64
CLT: 14.2.0.0.1.1668646533
Xcode: N/A
```

My Xcode command line tools appear to be in good working order: `xcode-select --install` tells me "command line tools are already installed" and `xcode-select -p` returns `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`. I don't believe I need to install the full Xcode and don't have the space at the moment, but can do that if needed.

I did also try downgrading to Xcode CLT 13.4 from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=Xcode) and re-installing, but got the same error message as above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: My advice would be to use [homebrew](https://brew.sh).  You can either install ruby itself (`brew install ruby`), or use homebrew to install one of the ruby managers such as `rvm`, `rbenv`, etc.

Comment: I kept getting the same error using rbenv, and using brew install did successfully install Ruby, but I kept getting permissions errors when trying to install a gem.

This [tutorial] (https://mac.install.guide/ruby/) from Daniel Kehoe on using asdf finally worked for me. Thanks for your help!